# Error on R package "eixport" installing: required C++11 or newer on macOS

Tags: r, macos, c++11, gdal

I am installing R package `eixport`on macOS High Sierra, but the error produced on `gdal` and `C++11` as following:

> checking GDAL: linking with --libs only... no
>   checking GDAL: linking with --libs and --dep-libs... no
>   In file included from gdal_test.cpp:1:
>   In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.3.1_1/include/gdal.h:45:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/2.3.1_1/include/cpl_port.h:187:6: error: Must have C++11 or newer.

I have tried to set to `libc++` but could not succeed.

Comment: Which versions of R and C++ compiler do you use?

Comment: I am using R version 3.4.3 and C++ version 4.2.1 (Apple LLVM version 9.1.0).

Comment: R 3.4.x no longer works with the compiler provided by Apple. See https://github.com/coatless/r-macos-rtools/blob/master/README.md for a simple way to get a compatible compiler.

Comment: Thanks Ralf, the problem was fixed. I followed your suggestion, and I also installed R 3.5.1 with gcc-8.